# Sticky rows in tree-like nested list structure

Tags: html, css

I have a long list of items that are nested.

```css
section#container {
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Bbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Cccccccccc</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Dddddddddddd</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>Eeeeeeeeee</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>Fffffffff</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div>Ggggg</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div>Hhhh</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div>Iiii</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <pre>More<br>content<br>so<br>we<br>can<br>scroll<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.</pre>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

When scrolling, I want to always see the "path that led to the current top row". For example, when scrolling further down, you should see

```
A                          # "Path"
   B                       # leading up to
      D                    # G (breadcrumbs)
         F                 #
            G
            H
            ...
```

Or maybe better visualized, see [THIS DEMO](https://marchaos.github.io/react-virtualized-sticky-tree/) of [marchaos/react-virtualized-sticky-tree](https://github.com/marchaos/react-virtualized-sticky-tree). It does exactly what I am looking for. The library however uses JavaScript and just sets the `top` property according to the nest level. I am looking for a simple CSS-only solution (independent on the amount of recursion), which I think should be fairly basic but I cannot seem to find a solution.

In the snippet above I attempted so with `position:sticky` on the `div`s, and it somewhat works, but they are unfortunately all *on the same line*. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to an individual content in order to differentiate it from the other contents which doesn't have [`sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) position and set the [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top) of an them.

Remember to set [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top) which is different from the one another in order to align them one under another because if you set the same [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top) will cause an overlapping.

### the following is an example

```css
section#container {
  height: 240px;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

div {
  position: sticky;
}

.first {
  z-index: 99999;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
}

.second {
  z-index: 99999;
  background: blue;
  top: 15px;
}

.third {
  z-index: 99999;
  background: green;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="first">Aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Bbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>Cccccccccc</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="second">Dddddddddddd</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>Eeeeeeeeee</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="third">Fffffffff</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div>Ggggg</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div>Hhhh</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div>Iiii</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <pre>More<br>content<br>so<br>we<br>can<br>scroll<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.</pre>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Sure, setting the `top` manually for all elements will work... like the example I linked in the question. But you cant really do that without Javascript if you dont know what the data will look like, or cannot control it. Also in your solution, the divs still weirdly overlap each other, even with a background applied to it. I guess that could only be solved by also manually applying specific z-indices to .first, .second etc.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that your solution is indeed the only way to do it. There does not seem to be a way to apply the `top` property depending on the nesting level, in any way. To prevent the necessity for classes `first`, `second` and so on and to effectively result in a CSS-only solution, you could also select them via `#container > ul > li`, `#container > ul > li > ul > li`, `#container > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li` etc.